# Fiware wirecloud widget upload: error no valid parser found

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I want to create a widget and upload it to my FIWARE Mashup Workspace. When I upload my ".wgt" file I get the error:

> Error adding packaged resource: Error parsing config.xml descriptor
>   file: No valid parser found.

How can I get more information about the error? 
Is it simply a parsing error, or is something different went wrong (no valid parser found sounds like some service is missing)

Is there a way to check my `config.xml` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a configuration error; there is no service missing.
Since your config is in xml, check it with an XML checker, to be sure that no opening/closing tags are missing.

If your wgt is an operator, check that your preferences/endpoints have different IDs. Also, please be sure that all your endpoints use distinct names

Comment: Yes, there was a closing tag missing. Now it works. Still for me is the question how to get more information when parsing fails, like the line number, or at least a better message than the misleading "no valid parser found".

Comment: Currently, I don't think there is a way to get more information.
Also, if the answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.